# How do i search for 2 of the same numbers in a list? (python)

Tags: python, list

Lets say my list consists of `n = [0,1,0,2,2,0,0]`

```
if 2 in n and 2 in n
print ("There are 2's")

elif 2 in n
print ("just one 2")
```

how do i make it find both 2's before print statement, otherwise it just prints it if theres just onw

Comment: so you want to know the frequency of the element in your list ?

Comment: `print(n.count(2))` ?

Comment: is there another way for this particular task im doing were arnt allowed to use list methods such as count

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `count` method of `list`,

```
>>> n
[0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0]
>>> elm = 2
>>> print("There are {} {} in {}".format(n.count(elm), elm, n))
There are 2 2 in [0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

or just count it manually if you can't use any method of `list` like `count`,

```
>>> print("There are {} {:d} in {}".format(len([1 for x in n if x == elm]), elm, n))
There are 2 2 in [0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `count` method.

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.count(x)
>   Return the number of times x appears in the list.

```
n = [0,1,0,2,2,0,0]
print(n.count(2))
#2

n = [0,1,0,1,2,0,0]
print(n.count(2))
#1

n = [0,1,0,1,1,0,0]
print(n.count(2))
#1
0
```

To write your own count method, just iterate over the list, and increment counter when you see the expected number

```
def count_n(li, num):

    c = 0
    #Iterate over the list using for loop
    for n in li:
        #If you see the number, increment the count
        if num == n:
            c+=1
    #Return count
    return c


print(count_n([0,1,0,2,2,0,0], 2))
#2
print(count_n([0,1,0,2,1,0,0], 2))
#1
print(count_n([0,1,0,1,1,0,0], 2))
#0
print(count_n([],2))
#0
```

Comment: is there another way for this particular task im doing were arnt allowed to use list methods such as count

Comment: Sure! Updated in the answer! @MarcusPaulson Please check!

Comment: Hi @MarcusPaulson , if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick next to the answer, else please ask if you have any questions for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(int)

n = [0,1,0,2,2,0,0]

for i in n:
    dic[i]+=1

element = 2
if element in dic.keys():
    print("frequency of {} in list is {}.".format(element, dic[element]))
else:
    print("element {} not present in list".format(element))
```

output

```
frequency of 2 in list is 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = [0,1,0,2,2,0,0]
count=0 # counter

for item in n: # For loops iterate over a given sequence.
     if item == 2: # check if item is 2
          count += 1 # This is the same as count = count + 1

# if...else statement: Decision making is required when we want to execute a code only if a certain condition is satisfied.
if count>1:
     print ("There are 2's")
elif  count ==1:
     print ("just one 2")
```

.

```
n = [0,1,0,2,2,0,0]
count=0 # counter
# list comprehension
count = sum([1 for item in n if item == 2]) # Single Line For Loops
# expr1 if condition1 else expr2 if condition2 else expr
print ("There are 2's" if count >1 else "just one 2" if count == 1 else "") #ternary expression
```

> **Ternary Operators** Ternary operators are more commonly known as conditional expressions in Python. These operators evaluate something
>   based on a condition being true or not.
>
> syntax: **condition_if_true if condition else condition_if_false**
>
> example of using these conditional expressions:
>
> ```
> is_nice = True
> state = "nice" if is_nice else "not nice"
> ```
>
> **It allows to quickly test a condition instead of a multiline if statement.**

.

> **List Comprehensions**
>
> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists.
>
> It consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for
>   clause, then zero or more for or if clauses.
>
> The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression
>   in the context of the for and if clauses which follow it.
>
> The list comprehension always returns a result list.  If you used to
>   do it like this:
>
> ```
> new_list = []
> for i in old_list:
>     if filter(i):
>         new_list.append(expressions(i))
> ```
>
> You can obtain the same thing using list comprehension:
>
> ```
> new_list = [expression(i) for i in old_list if filter(i)]
> ```